# Two SQLite queries at one go

Tags: sqlite

I have two queries:

```
SELECT word FROM dictionary WHERE lang = 'english' AND word LIKE 'k%' LIMIT 10;
SELECT word FROM dictionary WHERE lang = 'english' AND word LIKE 's%' LIMIT 10;
```

Because the database is huge, each query takes time. So, my question is that can I merge the above queries into one with a **LIMIT** of 5 each? If yes, then how to do it?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this:

```
SELECT * from (select word FROM dictionary WHERE lang = 'english' AND word LIKE 'k%' LIMIT 5)
UNION ALL
SELECT * from (select word FROM dictionary WHERE lang = 'english' AND word LIKE 's%' LIMIT 5);
```

Also to retrieve the data in a faster way you can create `index` on your column.

Comment: **Note(1)** `UNION ALL` includes the eventual duplicates, while `UNION` doesn't. **Note(2)**: The indices should be created on all the columns partecipating in the `WHERE` and `JOIN` clauses.

Comment: If I place ';' before UNION, it gives me words with only 'k'.
And if I don't place it, it shows an error as "LIMIT clause should come after UNION ALL not before". Any help?

Comment: @Sibir:- Updated my answer. Also you can use UNION in place of UNION ALL if you dont want the duplicates!

Comment: @RahulTripathi Kudos man!! It worked. One more thing. What did you mean by "Also to retrieve the data in a faster way you can create index on your column."?? I am new to database, could you please explain with some edit in the code you provided??

Comment: @Sibir:- You can go through the document of index: https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createindex.html Basically indexes are created for the faster retrieval of data from the table(specially huge tables like in your case). It is created like `CREATE INDEX myindex_idx ON dictionary (lang);`. Similarly you can create for other columns involved in your `where` clause.

Comment: @RahulTripathi `lang` does not have a high selectivity, so this is unlikely to help. Better would be a case insensitive index on `word`.

Comment: @CL.:- Indeed. I just took it as an example to show how we create index considering OP as newbie for database